# Is there disadvantages in staying idle with hunger?

Tags: nutrition, hunger-hungry

I usually take lunch at 2 PM and take dinner at 9 PM without any snacks or coffee in between. I will take a glass of green tea and two liters of water in between lunch and dinner. I feel hungry around 7 and I don't eat anything until 9.

Can staying hungry have any effect on health ? If so, what measures do I need to take ?